# nodejs query postgres using WHERE

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express

I have nodejs with a postgres db that i can run queries via API.

If I can curl with localhost:3000/data/ID# and i get data back. The code below is working.

```
const getDataById = (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
}
```

Below is an example of curl with ID# working as expected.

```
$ curl localhost:3000/data/2
{"id":2,"city":"dallas","data":{"user":"tim","position":"clerk"}}
```

I need to do the same but use the city name as my parameter.

I need to be able do the same but make the query with column values other than the ID#. For example in the database I can run

```
data=> SELECT * FROM data WHERE city = 'dallas';
```

and my results are the same:
`{"id":2,"city":"dallas","data":{"user":"tim","position":"clerk"}}`

I have tried the using the below but I come up empty on the results:

```
const getDataCity = (request, response) => {
    const city = (request.params.city)
     pool.query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE city = $1',[city], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
}
```

```
$ curl localhost:3000/data/dallas
$
```

Any help or guidance on how I can or should format the query is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Make sure a) that `getDataCity` is actually called, as it appears to be on the same route as`getDataById` and b) that `request.params.city` is what you expect. Otherwise, the SQL itself seems fine

Comment: "*example of curl with ID# working as expected*" - the code you've shown does send `results.rows`, which is an array. Why do we not see that as the response?

Comment: "*`if (error) { throw error }`*" - don't do that. Log the error, then `response.status(500).json(null)`.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - curl with ID# is the following: $ curl localhost:3000/data/2
the output is: {"id":2,"city":"dallas","data":{"user":"tim","position":"clerk"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix, actually turned out to be a typo. The problem was PEBCAK. The code was here correct. But in my application; i had something else. It was the following in the app.

`response.status(200).json(results.row)`

So I changed it to `(results.rows)` like it should have been and magically things work, now :)

```
const getDataCity = (request, response) => {
    const city = (request.params.city)
     pool.query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE city = $1',[city], (error, results) => {
       if (error) {
            console.log('error:', error)
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
}
```

```
$ curl localhost:3000/data/dallas
$ {"id":2,"city":"dallas","data":{"user":"tim","position":"clerk"}}
```

I also did stop throwing the error and logged it; because it is good practice, thanks @Bergi for that call out.

The actual fix is making sure you review all code and catch things.